# How to output 0 clicks before pressing button in JavaScript? (click counter)

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I made a click counter in JavaScript and now, I want to fix this problem:

When I open my click counter, output is nothing. But after pressing "Click" button, output is `1`. I want to change output to `0` after opening click counter. But here's another problem. After do that, output will `0` always after reloading page.

Here is code of my click counter:

```
document.title = 'Click Counter';

var clickButton = document.createElement('button');
var resetButton = document.createElement('button');
var output = document.createElement('p');

clickButton.innerHTML = 'Click';
resetButton.innerHTML = 'Reset';

clickButton.onclick = clickCounter;
resetButton.onclick = resetClicks;

document.body.appendChild(clickButton);
document.body.appendChild(resetButton);
document.body.appendChild(output);

function clickCounter() {
    if (localStorage.clicks) {
        localStorage.clicks = Number(localStorage.clicks) + 1;
    } else {
        localStorage.clicks = 1;
    }
    output.innerHTML = localStorage.clicks;
}

function resetClicks() {
    localStorage.clear();
    output.innerHTML = 0;
}
```

Comment: If you always want to start it at `0` why use `localStorage`?

Comment: @StackSlave I don't want to start it at `0`.

Comment: @StackSlave I want to output `0` **before pressing button**.

Comment: `output.textContent = 0;` not in a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your function has not been called once, the value of this variable must be null or undefined, you can treat this condition with an "if" adding the 0 to the output, and you will not have the problem when refreshing the page, because after the clicks the variable will have value. Am I right?

```
if (!localStorage.clicks){
    localStorage.clicks = 0;
}
```

Another tip, try to get the event when you open the counter and set the value under this event.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the localStorage.clicks as 0 if not defined yet.

```
...
document.body.appendChild(clickButton);
document.body.appendChild(resetButton);
document.body.appendChild(output);

if (!localStorage.clicks){
    localStorage.clicks = 0;
}

function clickCounter() {
    localStorage.clicks++;
    output.innerHTML = localStorage.clicks;
}


function resetClicks() {
...
```